# Kibana with plugins running on Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, azure-aks

I'm trying to install Kibana with a plugin via the `initContainers` functionality and it doesn't seem to create the pod with the plugin in it.

The pod gets created and Kibana works perfectly, but the plugin is not installed using the yaml below.

[initContainers Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-init-containers-plugin-downloads.html)

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.11.2
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: quickstart
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: install-plugins
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/fbaligand/kibana-enhanced-table/releases/download/v1.11.2/enhanced-table-1.11.2_7.11.2.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Got Kibana working with plugins by using a custom container image

dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.11.2
RUN /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-plugin install https://github.com/fbaligand/kibana-enhanced-table/releases/download/v1.11.2/enhanced-table-1.11.2_7.11.2.zip
RUN /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana --optimize
```

yaml

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.11.2
  image: my-conatiner-path/kibana-with-plugins:7.11.2
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: quickstart
```

Answer (score 0):

Building you own image would sure work, though it could be avoided in that case.

Your initContainer is pretty much what you were looking for.
With one exception: you need to add some emptyDir volume.

Mount it to both your initContainer and regular kibana container, sharing the plugins you would install during init.

Although I'm not familiar with the Kibana CR, here's how I would do this with elasti.co official images:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: official-kibana:x.y.z
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/kibana/plugins
          name: plugins
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - |
          set -xe
          if ! ./bin/kibana-plugin list | grep prometheus-exporter >/dev/null; then
              if ! ./bin/kibana-plugin install "https://github.com/pjhampton/kibana-prometheus-exporter/releases/download/7.12.1/kibanaPrometheusExporter-7.12.1.zip"; then
                  echo WARNING: failed to install Kibana exporter plugin
              fi
          fi
        name: init
        image: official-kibana:x.y.z
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/kibana/plugins
          name: plugins
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: plugins
```